# Tween.js Not Calling onUpdate Function

Tags: javascript, typescript, tween.js

I am using tweenjs and Typescript to change the x and y coordinates of a three.js cube.  I created the following tween to change the x position of an item of class "FallingItem".

```
this.movementArcData.horzTween = new TWEEN.Tween(this.movementArcData.pos.x)
                .to(this.movementArcData.newPos.x, this.movementArcData.movementTime * 1000)
                .onUpdate(this.updateXPos)
                .onComplete(this.horzTweenComplete);
```

where "this.movementArcData" is an object containing the following:

- horzTween - the tween itself
- pos.x - the original position of the item
- movementTime - the time it takes to complete the movement, 2000 milliseconds
- updateXPos - a member function of the a FallingItem object with the following code:

  updateXPos(){
      this.mesh.position.x = this.movementArcData.pos.x;
      console.log("update x: " + this.movementArcData.pos.x);
  }

horzTweenComplete - a member funtion of the FallingItem object with the following code:

```
horzTweenComplete(){
    this.movementArcData.horzTweenComplete = true;
}
```

Neither the updateXPos or horzTweenComplete callback is getting fired.

I am calling TWEEN.update in my render loop like so:

```
TWEEN.update(dt);
```

Since the tween's onComplete event never fires, the TWEEN.update is called constantly.  What am I missing that is causing the tween not to work properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tween.js needs to be passed the elapsed time, not a delta time.  Passing a running elapsed time fixed the problem.

Also, it's supposed to be passed an object containing the value you want interpolated.  It looks like passing the value itself doesn't work.  I had success with this:

```
let tweenElement = {
                x: this.tweenInfo.pos.x,
                y: this.tweenInfo.pos.y,
                item: this
            }

this.tweenInfo.tweenUp = new TWEEN.Tween(tweenElement)
                .to({y : this.tweenInfo.newPos.y}
                    , this.tweenInfo.movementTime * 0.5 * 1000)
                .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Cubic.InOut )
                .onUpdate(function(){
                    this.item.updateYPos(tweenElement, this)
                })
                .onComplete(function(){
                    this.item.tweenUpComplete();
                });
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. 
I'm using pixi and wanted to call TWEEN.update in app.ticker.add(...) and not in requestAnimationFrame().

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar case when `TWEEN` was not calling my `onUpdate` function. Found out I had to call [`window.requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) in order to tell the browser that I, i.e. `TWEEN`, "want to perform an animation and requests that the browser call a specified function to update an animation before the next repaint."

```
function animate(time) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    TWEEN.update(time);
}

new TWEEN
        .Tween({ y: 0 })
        .to({y: 1000}, 700)
        .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.InOut)
        .onUpdate(function () {
            window.scrollTo(0, this.y);
        })
        .start();

animate();
```

The above example was taken from https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js/blob/master/examples/00_hello_world.html.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... it helped remind me that I needed to add TWEEN.update() into my animation loop. Too much programming today methinks :)

Answer (score 0):

Another potential cause (I know probably not in this particular case) is that `TWEEN.removeAll()` is being called somewhere else in the code. One sign of this happening is that other tweens are working perfectly fine but some are not.