# why dont rotate an object whit its angle when i put a value

Tags: matter.js

I have a body but when I have other bodies inside this body and I put a value on its property "angle", and other bodies are rejected of this body.
now, for rotate this body, i tested its properties and found in "constraintImpulse" this property is not found in matters.js documentation, inside "constraintImpulse" it's found "angle" but this dont handle in radians, also, this movement made it with a tween

```
barra_izquierda_vaso_moleculas = Bodies.rectangle(200,200,10,200,{isStatic: true});
barra_derecha_vaso_moleculas = Bodies.rectangle(500,200,10,200,{isStatic: true});
barra_inferior_vaso_moleculas = Bodies.rectangle(350,300,300,10,{isStatic: true});

vaso_moleculas = Body.create({
    parts: [barra_izquierda_vaso_moleculas,barra_derecha_vaso_moleculas,barra_inferior_vaso_moleculas],
    restitution: 0,
    friction: 0,
    frictionStatic : 0,
    frictionAir: 0,
    inertia: Infinity,
    mass: 1,
    isStatic: true,
    });

World.add(world,vaso_moleculas);

createjs.Tween.get(vaso_moleculas.constraintImpulse).wait(2000).to({angle:0.06},3000);
```

Comment: Is it possible to put ele inside other ele (I mean on matter.js) ? I am not sure for that operation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to put update function for tween.

Something like that :

```
function animate(time) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    TWEEN.update(time);
}
```

Without update procedure we don't have a animation.

Look at [Tween.js Not Calling onUpdate Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35532103/tween-js-not-calling-onupdate-function)